# correlation for classification in python

Tags: python

I have Python dataframe df

It has multiple columns

```
Salary  Dept      Approve
1500    IT        Yes
1200    Finance   No
1200    IT        No
1300    HR        Yes
1800    Finance   No
1100    Finance   No
1600    Finance   No
1500    IT        Yes
1200    HR        Yes
1500    HR        Yes
```

I want to find the relation between Salary/Approve and Dept/Approve

Correlation is not working as some are classification not numerical

What other options do I have?
How can I find the correlation between Salary/Approve and Dept/Approve

Comment: better suited on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is by converting the categorical variables to dummies, and then computing correlations against each of them:

```py
dummies = pd.get_dummies(x)
```

From there it's easy to compute correlations between whatever combinations you like:

```py
>>> dummies.corr()
                Salary  Dept_Finance   Dept_HR   Dept_IT  Approve_No  Approve_Yes
Salary        1.000000      0.134865 -0.175072  0.030895   -0.047193     0.047193
Dept_Finance  0.134865      1.000000 -0.534522 -0.534522    0.816497    -0.816497
Dept_HR      -0.175072     -0.534522  1.000000 -0.428571   -0.654654     0.654654
Dept_IT       0.030895     -0.534522 -0.428571  1.000000   -0.218218     0.218218
Approve_No   -0.047193      0.816497 -0.654654 -0.218218    1.000000    -1.000000
Approve_Yes   0.047193     -0.816497  0.654654  0.218218   -1.000000     1.000000
```

Or a subset:

```py
>>> dummies[['Salary', 'Dept_HR']].corr()
           Salary   Dept_HR
Salary   1.000000 -0.175072
Dept_HR -0.175072  1.000000
```

Comment: Thanks but the correlation has to be against the whole column not just one category in it

Comment: Then I'm afraid you don't have many options. It does not make mathematical sense to compute correlation on an ordinal level. It's also worth noting that the `corr(c, approve_no)` is the negative of `corr(c, approve_yes)`, so you can get around some of it that way.